# How to Union 100+ tables with the same columns in PostGreSQL without typing out each table name?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I am pretty new to SQL and I am having trouble googling this. I have around a hundred tables in PostGreSQL that I need to union (fairly sure union is what I want) into one table. Every table has the same number of columns and column name, but different data. Basically I just want a master table of all the tables. All union posts I find seem to need you to type out each table name. This is not really realistic given the amount of tables I have.

I don't believe it matters, but if it does, these are spatial tables (using the PostGIS extension). I really appreciate it.

I have tried Union but I have too many tables to type out.

Comment: Are these partition tables?

Comment: Would it help to query all tables whose names are matching a pattern? If the names do not adhere to a pattern you most likely need to type the tables out regardless.

Comment: @wp78de Yes they all have a word in common that I could use. Otherwise their names are different and different lengths.

Comment: E.g. `select table_name from information_schema.tables
where table_name like 'gis_%' and table_type = 'BASE TABLE'`

Comment: If you don't have the table names recorded somewhere, then perhaps it would be easy to get the names from something like `select * from information_schema.tables`. Paste the table names to excel and just create a formula that would automatically write each query. Then just copy the code and paste back into your query editor. If you don't have to filter out tons of unnecessary tables, then you could accomplish all this is about 1 minute.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a view.  You would still need to list all the table names in the view definition, but would only have to do that once.  And even that once, it should be easy to script it, not need to type them all in by hand.

But really, you should use the partitioning feature.  It seems like you are trying to reinvent partitioning by hand, but it already exists.